# How do I connect to a GitHub Action's job's service?

Tags: postgresql, github, github-actions

GitHub Actions allow you to run background services on a per-job basis. After following the examples, I can't figure out how to connect to a running PostgreSQL container.

I've attempted a few different approaches in this [pull request](https://github.com/kyleconroy/dinosql/pull/58), but none of them have worked.

```
name: dinosql test suite
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432/tcp

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Test dinosql/ondeck
      run: go test -v ./...
      working-directory: internal/dinosql/testdata/ondeck
      env:
        PG_USER: postgres
        PG_DATABASE: postgres
        PG_PASSWORD: postgres
        PG_PORT: ${{ job.services.postgres.ports['5432'] }}
```

This setup results in the following [error](https://github.com/kyleconroy/dinosql/runs/193714282):

```
Run go test -v ./...
=== RUN   TestQueries
=== PAUSE TestQueries
=== RUN   TestPrepared
=== PAUSE TestPrepared
=== CONT  TestQueries
=== CONT  TestPrepared
--- FAIL: TestPrepared (0.00s)
##[error]    db_test.go:212: db: postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:32768/postgres?sslmode=disable
##[error]    db_test.go:212: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:32768: connect: connection refused
--- FAIL: TestQueries (0.00s)
##[error]    db_test.go:83: db: postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:32768/postgres?sslmode=disable
##[error]    db_test.go:83: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:32768: connect: connection refused
FAIL
FAIL    example.com/ondeck  0.005s
?       example.com/ondeck/prepared [no test files]
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The tests should pass if a valid database connection could be made.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem and found this [example](https://github.com/actions/example-services/blob/master/.github/workflows/postgres-service.yml) via GitHub's [code search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22job.services%22+path%3A.github%2F&type=Code) after a *lot* of trial and error.

```
name: dinosql test suite
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports:
          - 5432/tcp
        # needed because the postgres container does not provide a healthcheck
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master

    - name: Test dinosql/ondeck
      run: go test -v ./...
      working-directory: internal/dinosql/testdata/ondeck
      env:
        # use postgres for the host here because we have specified a contaienr for the job.
        # If we were running the job on the VM this would be localhost
        PG_HOST: postgres
        PG_USER: postgres
        PG_DATABASE: postgres
        PG_PASSWORD: postgres
        PG_PORT: ${{ job.services.postgres.ports['5432'] }}
```

Adding the healthcheck options and changing the database hostname from `127.0.0.1` to `postgres` should do the trick.

It appears that without the healthcheck options, the postgres container will be shut down and won't be available for the tests.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the example service configuration. Using it, I was able to fix my problem. You can see the commit [here](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/commit/b0745a45d89a00e58adc246cc24b9be7448d1e76). Sadly, the YAML you posted doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: "Adding the healthcheck options and changing the database hostname from 127.0.0.1 to postgres should do the trick." I use MySQL and suffered from connection refused for a long time.  Thanks for this answer. It resolve my problem with change host name to "mysql" from 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running your job in a container, like in this example which is running on a VM `ubuntu-latest`, you should still use `localhost` and just map the ports

```
services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          # Maps tcp port 5432 on service container to the host
          - 5432:5432
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/creating-postgresql-service-containers#running-jobs-directly-on-the-runner-machine